Maya Polyseparate without creating parent groups
polySeparate -s 0 -ch 1;
parent -w;
source cleanUpScene;
    deleteEmptyGroups;
    deleteUnusedSets;

I need help with a MEL script. I'm trying to separate the selected polygons into new object without creating parent groups.
However, when I take the original polyseparate command and delete the object name at the start, Maya doesn't understand what I want to separate - it outputs "Invalid selection: polySeparate needs exactly 1 polygonal object or polygonal faces from one object."
How I can Polyseparate polys and not create a parent for any of them?
